# Присваивание строковому ресурсу значения edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, строки

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню строковому ресурсу присваивалось текст из `EditText`? Именно строковому ресурсу в `string.xml`.

Comment: Вы хотите поменять значение в string.xml?

Comment: Вам нужно сохранить строку, чтобы использовать её при последующих открытиях приложения? Или зачем?

Comment: В строковом ресурсе храниться название textview из другого activity. Я хочу сделать чтобы когда я нажимал на определенный пунк в меню во втором activity название textview в первом изменялось на текст в edittext во втором. (для понимания этот пункт называется сохранить)

Comment: Тогда ответ уже дан. Сохраняйте строку не в ресурсах, а в файле.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ресурсы приложения, в том числе все строки в `string.xml`, невозможно поменять в рантайме.

Если вы хотите сохранить строку и переиспользовать в будущем, то делайте это, к примеру, через [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) или в свой файл пишите.